# Nextjs: How do I pass cookie from SSR to browser?

Tags: next.js

I have a fetch('/setCookies'), which sets some cookie for the client.

If I run it on the client, the cookie shows up.

If I run it on the server, the cookie does not show up on the browser.

I have tried setting explicitly domain name,,,etc...

```
const Page = async () => {
   await fetch('/setCookies') <--- runs on server
   return <Clinet/> 
}
```

Comment: Please share your setCookies route handler code

Comment: this is an seperate express server that simply uses res.cookies(...). I am not using nextjs edge functions